# passing comma separated values in filter query of solr response

Tags: facet, solr

I want to pass comma separated values in filter query (fq) of solr response, currently when i want to pass multiple categories i use OR operator.
like this  fq=categoryId:3 OR categoryId:55 OR categoryId:34

is there any solution to pass values like fq=categoryId:3,55,34

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`fq=categoryId:(3 55 34)` should work if your default operator is OR. Else, try `fq=categoryId:(3 OR 55 OR 34)`. This is called [Field Grouping](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/queryparsersyntax.html#Field%20Grouping) in the Lucene query syntax. (Solr supports the full Lucene syntax as documented [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax#lucene).)

Answer (score 1):

if your field for filter query is of type text or string, you can also use fq=categoryId:(IN 3 55 34 44) as well. But IN operator will not work with integer fileds or other then string/text fields.